# Profile qualification is using entitlement definitions that may be out of date

Tags: github-actions, xcodebuild

I'm using a GitHub Actions to try and build my App.

The build fails as it says my provisioning profile doesn't match my entitlements file which when I compare they don't. However, how does the provisioning profile know it should get updated, i.e, one entitlement is: `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only` - that's not in the provisioning profile. What can I do to update it?

It looks like `app sandbox` just isn't in the profile.

I've setup the following:

- Manual Provisioning Profile for signing
- Signing Cert in GitHub Secrets
- Provisioning profile in GitHub Secrets
- Custom keychain created on each build, profiles/certs setup

```yaml
- name: Build
  run:  xcodebuild build -workspace "myProject.xcworkspace" -scheme "myProject" -configuration Release -destination "platform=macOS"
```

However, when I try to build I get:

```
/Users/runner/work/myProject/myProject: error: Provisioning profile "myProject_macOS_Distribution_Profile" doesn't include the com.apple.security.app-sandbox,
com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only,
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write,
com.apple.security.get-task-allow,

** BUILD FAILED **

com.apple.security.network.client,
com.apple.security.network.server,
and com.apple.security.print entitlements. Profile qualification is using entitlement definitions that may be out of date. Connect to network to update.
```

I have googled this error, but there seems to be zero results of it.

My `entitlements.plist` looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.print</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue on bitrise, another CI platform.

Comment: What does your `entitlements.plist` look like? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Regarding "**Manual Provisioning Profile for signing**", how do you do this? Did you try [editing](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-profiles/edit-download-or-delete-profiles) it to match your entitlements?

Comment: @Azeem - sorry no, I haven't been able to do this, I feel like I need a way to make it match

Comment: Right. What does your workflow look like? The relevant parts. Also, please mention the target of your app. Is it going to App Store or just codesigned/notarized for custom distribution?

Answer (score 0):

After wasting days on this, I finally found the solution in the [apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731656).

In my case, I am building a Mac OSX application, and the [Github guide assumes](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development#add-a-step-to-your-workflow) you're doing something for iOS. There is a little note that explains how to solve the issue:

> Note: For iOS build targets, your provisioning profile should have the extension .mobileprovision. For macOS build targets, the extension should be  .provisionprofile. The example workflow above should be updated to reflect your target platform.